# jQuery UI Slider giving: Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the jQuery slider plugin but it keeps giving the JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

Here is the script:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/

You can view a demo here:
[link-removed]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The plugin you're using to convert the slectbox to the slider requires the selectbox to have an `id` attribute.

Simply add `id="slider"` to the selectbox and it should work.

Comment: Removing # or href="#" seems to make no difference?